# Test Camel Route that starts by waiting for a file to arrive

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, apache-camel

I have a Camel route that waits for a zip file to be received in a directory. It unzips it and then iterates over the files it contains, parsing their contents before sending them on to one of a number of message queues.

I have got the route to work end to end, but now I want to write unit tests to handle the different cases that might arise. And I'm falling at the first hurdle.

All the unit tests that I have been able to find on the internet seem to start with a message being received by the first component in the route. I need to simulate the existence of a file.

My route is configured in a Spring context file, and I can see that my routes are being adviced ( for example : `Adviced endpoint [file:///tmp/dta/xml_source?antInclude=*.zip&move=.done&moveFailed=.error] with mock endpoint [mock:file:/tmp/dta/xml_source]` )

I just don't know how to kick it into action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the advice from `mock:` to `seda:` or `direct:` and use a `ProducerTemplate` to send a message to the starter endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply advice your consumer (i.e. FILE) to point to a test resource directory with specific file name and make sure the noop=true so test does not delete the file.
This way you are not mocking this endpoint and your route runs just as in a real scenario.

```
replaceFromWith("file:///TEST_RESOURCE_DIRECTORY/dta/xml_source?antInclude=*.zip&move=.done&moveFailed=.error&noop=true")
```